# Unable to skip Grub v. 2.02 boot menu on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bootloader, grub2

I have one OS on my Lenovo Flex 5 15 - Elementary OS 5 (just one of many distributions based on Ubuntu 18.04).
When I turn my laptop on, Grub v. 2.02 boot menu appears and I have 30 seconds to choose (start loading of Elementary or Setup, for instance).

I want to skip this boot menu and have Elementary start by default.
I've tried to edit **/etc/default/grub**, but it didn't change a thing. Here's my /etc/default/grub content:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="elementary"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="5"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="true"
```

I've already tried unsuccessfully to change grub config via Grub Customizer. Here's a screenshot of options that I changed:

[image: Grub Customizer Screenshot]

Comment: sorry, you didn't mention that - did you `update-grub`?